# ZFS Pool (Raidz2) of 23 disks + 1 spare. Good/Bad?

Tags: raid, zfs, truenas

I'm creating ONE Raidz2 Pool with 23 drives and a hot spare. (I know the hot spare isn't fully supported yet but thats fine)

Is it a bad idea to use this many disks in a single pool?

What would the consequences be if I did do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad. Scrap it and use a distribution with a newer version of ZFS and features. [NexentaStor is a good bet](http://nexentastor.org/).

So why do I say it's bad? That pool layout goes against ZFS best practices. [Please read here first](http://www.nex7.com/readme1st).

*For RAIDZ2, start at 6 disks and do not exceed 12 disks in each vdev...*

also..

*try to have an even number of disks in the vdev if using raidz2...*

Consequences include poor I/O performance (ZFS scales with the number of vdevs/groups of RAID disks), long rebuild times and the fact that mirrors will always outperform.

What are you planning to do with this storage setup?

Comment: nas4free also has a new version of zfs.

Comment: Just office file storage. Documents and such.